# AFNetworking 2.0 Reachability incorrectly reports not reachable - AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable

Tags: ios, reachability, afnetworking-2

I'm using the reachability feature of AFNetworking 2.0 as outlined in their sample code - I have a test server in the local LAN that my iOS App communicates with during testing. When I run the app in the simulator with WLAN on, AFNetworking initially reports that the server/URL is reachable, but then changes it back to not reachable (even though the server is there, reachable and WLAN is working fine). This means that it turns the operations queue off so the app won't communicate with the server, even though it most certainly could.

Any suggestions why AFNetworking incorrectly reports the local server/URL as not reachable?

Here's my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *mgr = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.188.20:3000/"]];
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.httpManager.operationQueue;

[mgr.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
   {
        NSLog(@"Reachability for %@ has changed to %@", @"http://192.168.188.20:3000/",AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));


        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                NSLog(@"re-enabling operation queue");
                [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            default:
                NSLog(@"disabling operation queue");
                [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
    }];
```

When I run the app I get the following log output - WLAN is working fine, local server is running at the given IP and port number:

```
Jan 31 13:21:04  MyApp[10671] <Warning>: Reachability for http://192.168.188.20:3000/ has changed to Reachable via WiFi
Jan 31 13:21:04  MyApp[10671] <Warning>: re-enabling operation queue
Jan 31 13:21:04  MyApp[10671] <Warning>: Reachability for http://192.168.188.20:3000/ has changed to Not Reachable
Jan 31 13:21:04  MyApp[10671] <Warning>: disabling operation queue`
```

The same thing happens when I try it with a live server, i.e. outside the local LAN. However it does not always happen.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions why the reachability is incorrectly changed back to Not Reachable after initially being correctly reported as being ok ?

Comment: I seem to be getting this same behaviour, but not sure on a resolution.

Comment: Dd you get a solution for this. I am also struggling with the same issue. My API returns Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." randomly while device is connected to the network.